# Lightbox using CSS problem [photos attached]

Tags: javascript, html, css, lightbox

I am using [this](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2007/08/22/create-a-lightbox-effect-only-with-css-no-javascript-needed/) website for making a CSS lightbox.

After I put the button on top of my webpage, the light box is appearing only on the top division (div tag) of the website. I want the light box to appear in the middle of the website. Can anyone help me in resolving the issue? Photos attached before and after. The light box is appearing only on the top not in the center of the webpage.

## **Before**:

[image]

==============================================================

## **After**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the css in the URL you mentioned. The .white-content and .black-overlay divs shouldn't be inside other divs. Only the link that says "light box here" (or maybe it's a button instead) should be contained in the top div.